# Pulling data from list based on a particular column

Tags: list, custom-list

I am currently facing a problem with a requirement.
I have a list say A which has columns which are

```
('Id','Product Name','Part number','product serial number','Assign To','float location').
```

Now i will have another list say B which will have columns which are

`('ID','Product Name','Part number','Product serial number','float location','customer','job card number')`.

Now I have been told that the B List will contain data based on `Assign To` column say if the value of `Assign To` column is John then only John can see the data in the B list and no one else.

I am working on SharePoint online so the login is not my issue it is the logic which has to be build up in order to make this possible.
Please if anyone knows this does help me.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify view of list B and add one filter. From dropdown select `Assign To` and in value textbox write **[Me]**

This will show items which have current user in `Assign To` column

Comment: Thanks actually i found this before only but this is the correct answer so i am marking this.
Thanks